# Parse a substring in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

Given a string, e.g.:

`RT @John: Hello world! @Peter Hello!`

I'd like to be able to get the part between 'RT @' and ':'. How can I accomplish this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a simple [SUBSTRING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) could solve your problem:

```
SELECT substring('RT @John: Hello world! @Peter Hello!', 'RT @(.*):');
```